# Array is being altered but wasn't used in left-side assignment

Tags: javascript

```
var userID = 1;
var users = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(users + " initial users array");

testFunction();

function testFunction() {
    var usersWithoutMe = users; // altering usersWithoutMe alters users from now on
    var index = usersWithoutMe.indexOf(userID);
    if (index != -1) {
      usersWithoutMe.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(usersWithoutMe + " new users array without my own id");

}

console.log(users + " initial users array got altered");
```

How can I prevent this from happening, and why is it doing this?

Note: I fixed it by doing : `var usersWithoutMe = users.slice(0);` instead of just `var usersWithoutMe = users` and it fixed it, but I'd still like to understand why it didn't work initially...

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Comment: You never copied the array, so you're modifying the same instance.

Comment: It's the same array, just a new reference. You have to copy it `var usersWithoutMe = users.slice(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you are modifying the same array. Your line

```
// altering usersWithoutMe alters users from now on
var usersWithoutMe = users;
```

Is incorrect in the sense you understand it. `usersWithoutMe` now points to the same array as the `users` variable. And then your line:

```
usersWithoutMe.splice(index, 1);
```

Is changing the array in place. Since both points to the same underlying array, you see the changes in both variables.

If you want to assign a copy, you can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var usersWithoutMe = users.slice(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you set a new array to an old one, you are basically making two arrays, both *referencing* the same array, not creating one new array with the same values as the old one. Therefore, every time you modify one, the array it refers to is being modified.

This holds true if you try to set objects equal to each other. To bypass this and clone the new array, you can use

```
var usersWithoutMe=users.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, Arrays and Objects are passed or assigned by reference.  That means when you do:

```
var usersWithoutMe = users;
```

You are NOT making a copy of the `users` array.  You are simply make a second variable that also points to the same array.  So, when you then modify `usersWithoutMe` here:

```
usersWithoutMe.splice(index, 1);
```

You are modifying the one and only array you have, the same one that `users` points to.

If you want to actually make a shallow copy of the users array, you can user `users.slice(0)` to make a copy and assign that copy to `usersWithoutMe` like this:

```
var userID = 1;
var users = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(users + " initial users array");

testFunction();

function testFunction() {
    var usersWithoutMe = users.slice(0); // make shallow copy of users
    var index = usersWithoutMe.indexOf(userID);
    if (index != -1) {
      usersWithoutMe.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(usersWithoutMe + " new users array without my own id");

}

console.log(users + " initial users not altered");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/G2suE/

Answer (score 0):

### `slice` makes a new array.

Assigning `users` to a variable and then modifying that variable actually modifies `users` because a *reference* to `users` was stored, not a new mutable array separate of `users`.